# How to make helm-projectile-rg list files in relative to project?

Tags: helm, projectile, helm-projectile

Whenever I use helm-projectile-rg I see the list of files in relative to the current file:

```
../../../../../../project_dir/test/test1/filex.cpp   "match"
```

Is there a way to have it show files in relative to project like this:

```
test/test1/filex.cpp "match"
```

Comment: May I ask what system? for me helm-projectile-rg does give relative eg "./src/file.txt".

Comment: I am running on MacOS. I tried removing all customization of projectile, helm-projectile, helm-rg, helm. But I still see the same.